# Shared Preferences always returning true - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, boolean

I have a Database called `Person` and in that Database I have a bool value with a default value of false. In my app I change this value to true then save this change locally using Shared Preferences. When the bool is true it adds it to `Favourites.dart` page and if it is Joined it changes the color to green. Simple enough, but the `getbool` is always returning true even when I create a new `Person` in the Database. So when i create a new one the `Person['Joined']` (Person (Database) and Joined (bool)) is false but the `getbool` is true
**Home Page:**

```
Widget listItem({
    required Map Person,
   
  }) {
    
    void savebool() async {
      SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      await prefs.setBool("Person['Joined']", Person['Joined']);

      print(Person['Joined']);
    }

    return Slidable(
      startActionPane: ActionPane(
        motion: const BehindMotion(),
        extentRatio: 1 / 5,
        children: [
          SlidableAction(
            backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
            icon: Icons.add,
            label: 'Join',
            onPressed: (BuildContext context) {
              setState(() {
                Person['Joined'] = true;
              });
             
              savebool();
            },
```

**Favourites.dart** (this is the page where the problem is):

```
late bool joined;
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getPrefs(); // call the function here
  }

getPrefs() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {
      joined = prefs.getBool("Person['Joined']") ?? false;
      print("getbool: $joined");
      //PROBLEM IS HERE
      //joined is always returning true even though Person['Joined'] is false
      //Maybe it's the way im calling it?
    });
  }
```

`joined` is the value of the Shared Preferences `Person['Joined']` but when I print Person['Joined'] before I change the bool to true it is false but when I print `joined`, it is returning true, even when `Person['Joined']` is false.

Answer (score 0):

The issue might be with the key you are using to store and retrieve the boolean value from shared preferences. In the `listItem` widget, you are using the following key to save the boolean value:

```
await prefs.setBool("Person['Joined']", Person['Joined']);
```

This key contains the string `"Person['Joined']"`, which is not the key you want to use. Instead, you should use the following key:

```
await prefs.setBool("${Person['id']}_joined", Person['Joined']);
```

This key contains the ID of the person followed by `"_joined"`, which will be a unique key for each person. You can then retrieve this boolean value using the same key in the `getPrefs` function:

```
joined = prefs.getBool("${Person['id']}_joined") ?? false;
```

Make sure to use the correct key for each person when saving and retrieving the boolean value from shared preferences.

Comment: I'm struggling to reference `Person` and reference that in a `super initstate` at the same time it keeps giving the error: `Undefined name 'Person'.
Try correcting the name to one that is defined, or defining the name`. Any ideas? I have tried to move the code around so that it can reference both but I can't do it

Comment: After looking at the code for a while now, I can say that this is not going to work because the Shared Preferences doesn't know anything about my Database I'm just getting the bool from my database that's all so I don't think this is going to work